# Checking values of arrays returning false?

Tags: php, arrays, facebook

I need to check that 2 values from 2 different arrays are the same.
I am currently getting one value from mysql and the other from facebook api.

`$UserHomeTown[1]` is the users location and `$city_Value[1]` is the friends location but when i try and check the value between these i always get false.

Tested the statement by echoing out to screen and this is what i get

```
 if (Lancashire === United Kingdom) False 
 if (Lancashire === Lancashire) False
```

I have tried !=, !==, ===, == and still all i get is false,

Here is my code getting the information from facebook

```
$userFriend_profile = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=name,location');

$total = count($userFriend_profile['data']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total;)
{
    if(isset($userFriend_profile['data'][$i]['location']['name']))
    {
        $city_Value = explode(',',trim($userFriend_profile['data'][$i]['location']['name']));
        if ($city_Value[0] != $UserHomeTown[0]) { // This on works
        if (isset($city_Value[1])) {
            echo "if ($UserHomeTown[1] === $city_Value[1])";
            if ($UserHomeTown[1] === $city_Value[1]){
                echo "<br> True<br><br>";
            } else {
                echo "<br> False<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not see anything wrong in the code, Try

`if ($UserHomeTown[1] == $city_Value[1])` instead of `if ($UserHomeTown[1] === $city_Value[1])`

Answer (score 0):

The array `$city_Value[1]` was passing a space in front of the actual value which was not showing in the output but was returning false

The if statement was seeing `"Lancashire" == " Lancashire"`